# Replace one character in palindrome string to make it non palindrome python

Tags: python, palindrome

can you please help with following task I've encountered during online coding interview challenge.

As input you are given palindrome string, you can replace only one character in it and after modification it should meet 2 following conditions:

1. Be not a palindrome string
2. Be lexicographically less then original input string

I was not able to produce any solution. But here is my logic:

First of all string are immutable in python, so at first need to convert it to list. Then possibly using some kind of loop need to replace elements in list, then convert list back to string and check:

1.if string is palindrome
2.if it is lexicographically less.

But I don't understand with what I need to replace it? Should it be another nested loop which will iterate through[a-z]?

Comment: Right now the question is somewhat unclear and can be solved "vaguely" (lexicographically less is a broad category); could you provide the test input cases and their expected output?

Comment: Sounds like a trick question. With the input string "A", there's no way to make it a nonpalindrome just by replacing one instance of one character with another. If you're thinking "suppose the input is guaranteed to be longer than one character", then "\0\0" can be made into a nonpalindrome, but it can't be made lexicographically smaller, because "\0\0" is the lexicographically smallest string of length 2.

Comment: You right guys, seems I need to clarify few things.

Comment: So there was also condition that if it is not possible to do so, print IMPOSSIBLE, so this will take for example input A.   Regarding "lexicographically less", for example. Input 'acca' , expected output 'aaca'.  And input is only lowercase [a-z]

Comment: @Kevin i think the point is to find an algorithm to always find a solution if it can be found but also make it so it can say that it can't be done

Answer (score 1):

assuming the palindrome will only contain lowercase english alphabet (since we're talking about strings being lexicographically smaller) you need to just follow 3 rules:

1. replace the first character that isn't `'a'` with `'a'`
2. don't try to replace the middle character (since it won't affect whether or not the string is a palindrome)
3. if your new string is the same as your old string it means you couldn't find any solution so it can't be done

you don't need to check whether the outcome is a palindrome or not, if you changed one non-middle member you know it won't be a palindrome (since your input is guaranteed to be a palindrome) 
you also don't need to convert it to a list since strings already have all the functionality you need

the code for this could look like this:

```
pali = raw_input("insert a palindrome: ")

new_string = ""

replaced = False

for i, c in enumerate(pali):
    if not replaced:
        if c > 'a' and (len(pali)/2 != i or len(pali)%2 == 0):
            new_string += 'a'
            replaced = True
        else:
            new_string += c
    else:
        new_string += c
if new_string == pali:
    print "no way to change palindrome to non palindrome and make it lexicographically smaller"
else:
    print "new non palindrome lexicographically smaller string:", new_string
```

you can always change what character you check for instead of `'a'` depending on your definition of "lexicographically smaller"

Comment: Thanks for this, but actually strings in python are immutable. Do you say that this new_string +='a' replaces first element in string with 'a'?

Comment: they are immutable and as you can see i created a new string as i went along , the point is that you don't need lists to do string manipulation you can do it on strings directly. += creates a new string object in memory but that shouldn't bother you....

Comment: thanks for your reply. But what is your definition of "middle character"?  If there odd numbers of characters it is clear, but if it is even?

Comment: when it is even there is no middle character... that's reflected in the code too